# Recovering a dual boot

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multi-boot

My system at home used to have a dual boot of

1. Windows 7
2. Windows 7

Due to some requirements I have had to blow away my primary partition and make it XP.  So I now have;

1. XP
2. Windows 7

However, when I installed XP it deleted my dual boot menu.  Is there a way I can get the menu back again so I can boot into my Windows 7 environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the Windows 7 DVD? If so, boot from that and select Startup Repair.  Once you do that, you will have the Windows 7 boot manager running and can go from there.

Comment: Yes I do have the DVD.  Does it matter that XP is on the primary partition and 7 on the second one?  I don't want to blow away my XP environment.  Though that would be less of a hassle than blowing away my 7 env.

Comment: It shouldn't matter; if the boot manager does not detect your Windows XP install, you can always add it in manually once you are in Windows 7 - I used a program for this: http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/ (its free for personal use)

Comment: +1 great.  Thanks for this.  Will try when i get home and with any luck mark your answer as the correct one.  'Ave a good one.

Comment: Good luck - did this last night for my home PC :)

Comment: Ah, hehe, so you are fairly confident it works then!  Glad to know I didn't screw up too badly then.

Comment: Well, I did windows 7 install second to XP, but close enough (still use the same boot manager)

Comment: Had to do it three times and eventually Win 7 fired up and then I used EasyBCD.  Warning to anyone downloading from neosmart, you go through a lot of hoops before you get to download it and there are MANY diversionary download links for all sorts of rubbish!

Comment: @griegs Yay! EasyBCD is pretty easy to use too, right? I thought it was a very good GUI to the command line.

Comment: yeah it's awesome.  just being able to add the menu item, rename them and order them was so worth it.  i'd have paid for that.  thanks for the heads up

Comment: @griegs glad I could help out.